# Shell Breathing Modes and Base Excitation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics, vibration

I have been reviewing "Vibration of Continuous System" by S. Rao as part of self-studying to help with work. I started reviewing the chapter regarding shells and noticed that shells have beam and breathing modes (see picture below).

I was wondering, for a shell structure that is experiencing translational base excitation is there "an easy" method to show that the forced shell vibration does not have a significant contribution by the shell breathing modes?

Intuitively, I believe that the first shell mode (similar to a beam mode) would be the major contribution to the forced response. However, I'm not sure how to quantify this assumption.

Thank you!

[image: Shell modes]

Comment: this is over my head, but wouldn't it depend on excitation frequency? You might perhaps rule out the odd or even modes

Comment: @PeteW Thank you for the feedback. This is something I can look into.